About std::views::take_while
Consider the code:
std::vector a{3, 7, 8, 1, - 2, 4 };
auto view = a | std::views::take_while([](auto elem) {return elem > 0; });

Are there any standard means to get an iterator (or position) corresponding to the element of vector a following the last element entering the view, or can this be done only by tricks with lambda:
std::vector a{ 3, 7, 8, 11, -2, 4 };
auto        it{ a.begin() };
auto        lambda = [&it](auto elem)
                     {
                         bool result = (elem > 0);
                         if (result) ++it;
                         return result; 
                     };
auto        view = a | std::views::take_while(lambda);


std::views::drop_while will give you a view starting from the desired element. Will that do what you want?

Yes, you can use std::ranges::next, which is overloaded for sentinels. std::ranges::take_while_view::iterator is comparable to sentinels of the underlying range, e.g. you can use it with a.end().
std::vector a{3, 7, 8, 1, -2, 4 };
auto view = a | std::views::take_while([](auto elem) {return elem > 0; });
auto it = std::ranges::next(view.begin(), view.end());

// prints -2 4
for (auto i : std::ranges::subrange(it, a.end())) std::cout << i << "\n";


You seem to be using the wrong adaptor, a more appropriate one would be views::drop_while, as mentioned in the comments:
std::vector a{3, 7, 8, 1, -2, 4 };
auto view = a | std::views::drop_while([](auto elem) { return elem > 0; });

